# Prevent Changes to a Spotfire DXP

Tags: spotfire

Is there any way to prevent any changes (i.e., lock or hide) to the calculated columns or scripts in a Spotfire file (.dxp).

We are trying to deploy a template / file we built in Spotfire and would like our team to use it as is and prevent any accidental changes while we continue to work on updates etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can go about this. For scripting you can remove the scripting licenses from the users of the dxp. But this wouldn't prevent the calculated column changes. The best method, in my opinion, is duplication and versioning.

Deploy your live template to a public folder and then keep a backup in a folder where only you have access. Then, edit another copy of the template with a version control number like Template2_2.dxp. When you are ready to deploy it, just overwrite the live version. You will already have a back up of the live version, so now you just need to backup your newest one.

It's the most basic but easy method and ensures you don't leave room for mistakes or over limit your users by removing licenses.

Comment: I think you're right about the versioning, I think that may be the easiest. However, out of interest, how do you remove the scripting licenses?

Comment: Tools > Administration Manager > Groups and Licenses. Here are all of your groups, and you can click on the Licenses sub tab to see the licenses associated with them. So if you don't want your Professional Client Users to have scripting abilities, then click on this group then click licenses and edit the Spotfire Extensision licenses, Author Scripts. You can really make some custom groups here and give people explicit privlages.

Comment: What about rewriting a copy from an/admin/folder/template.dxp to the/public/folder/template.dxp using automation services? That way you could replace whatever accidental changes every day or so with the verbatim copy.

Comment: @jleviaguirre that's a solid idea.